# How to go from one definition of a derivative to another?

Tags: derivatives

How do we go from $\lim_{h\to0}=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ to $\lim_{h\to0}=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-Lh}{h}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} = L \Leftrightarrow \lim_{h \to 0} \left(\frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} - L\right) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a) - Lh}{h} = 0
$$

Comment: Just as an additional question, how do we know L = f'(a) in order for it to equal 0?

Comment: If you can find such an $L$ such that the equation is satisfied, then it's necessary and sufficient that $L = f'(a)$.

Comment: Is it possible for there to be a proof for that?

Comment: There's nothing to prove. The definition of $f'(a)$ is precisely $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}$.

Comment: AH I see it now, thanks!